Unique Hausdorff topology on trivial vector bundle?
Question: Is there a Hausdorff topology other than the product topology on $X\times \mathbb{C}^n$, that turns $(X\times \mathbb{C}^n, \mathrm{pr}_1)$ into a vector bundle, where $\mathrm{pr_1}$ denotes the projection onto the first component?
For me a vector bundle over topological space $X$ is a Hausdorff space $E$ together with a continuous surjection $p\colon E \to X$, such that fiber $E_x$ carries the structure of a vector space for every $x\in X$, and the maps $+\colon E\times_{p,p}E \to E$, $\cdot \colon \mathbb{C} \times E \to E$ and $0\colon X \to E,x \to 0_x$ are continuous.

If $X$ admits any non-trivial rank-$n$ vector bundle $(E,p\colon E\to x)$, then obviously $E \cong X \times \mathbb{C}^n$ as sets in such a way that $p$ becomes $\mathrm{pr}_1$. So the only thing distinguishes $E$ from $X\times \mathbb{C}^n$ is exactly the topology on it. One could also play some tricks like put a discrete topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (I haven't checked all the details in that case, though). If the substance of the question is different, please clarify.

I try to clarify the question: I want to find a topology on $X \times \mathbb{C}^n$, which is not the product topology, such that  $(X\times \mathbb{C}^n,\mathrm{pr}_1)$ is a vector bundle in the above sense, e.g., we have to find a topology on $X\times \mathbb{C}^n$ different to the product topology such that $\mathrm{pr_1}, +, \cdot, and the zero section are continuous. Or is this not possible?

Hmm, as far as I can tell, you've just repeated the original question and that question is answered in my comment.

I don't see in your comment above an answer to the question. The discrete topology on \mathbb{C}^n doesn't do it. The above mentioned axioms of a vector bundle imply that the every fiber $E_x$ of a vector bundle $(E,p)$ is a topological Hausdorff space. For $E=X \times \mathbb{C}^n$ every fiber could be identified with $\mathbb{C}^n$. But on $\mathbb{C}^n$ equipped with discrete topology is not a topological vector space (scalar multiplication is not continuous).

The question is motivated by the fact, that a finite-dimensional vector space has a unique Hausdorff topology, which turns it in a topological vector space. The question above asked, if one can generalize this fact to trivial bundles.

@PHmath The answer to your question is in the first sentence of Igor's first comment. Each isomorphism class of $n$-dimensional vector bundle over $X$ corresponds to a different topology on $X\times \mathbb{C}^n$ that answers your question affirmatively. I used this in a note I wrote many years ago that you can probably find on my webpage (under Research, and then Drafts). I will say that it is the only mathematical fact that I have ever seen people take offense to, in the same way that they take offense to an off-color joke. I can't explain this, but it has happened to me more than once.

Thank you, this helps a lot.
